# In Genesis 22:8-14, is there a difference between a ram and a lamb?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, animals, vayera, binding-of-isaac

Having taken a translation from [this website](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=1&CHAPTER=22), which I am told to have Orthodox Jewish credentials, I am referring to Genesis 22:8-14

> 'God will see to a **lamb** for an offering, my son,' replied Abraham. The
>   two of them continued together. When they finally came to the place
>   designated by God, Abraham built the altar there, and arranged the
>   wood. He then bound his son Isaac, and placed him on the altar on top
>   of the wood. Abraham reached out and took the slaughter knife to slit
>   his son's throat. God's angel called to him from heaven and said,
>   'Abraham! Abraham!' 'Yes.' 'Do not harm the boy. Do not do anything to
>   him. For now I know that you fear God. You have not withheld your only
>   son from Him.' Abraham then looked up and saw a ram caught by its
>   horns in a thicket. He went and got the **ram**, sacrificing it as an
>   all-burned offering in his son's place. Abraham named the place 'God
>   will See' (Adonoy Yir'eh). Today, it is therefore said, 'On God's
>   Mountain, He will be seen.'

Is there a difference between a lamb and a ram?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheep):

> Adult female sheep are referred to as ewes, **intact males as rams** or occasionally tups, castrated males as wethers, and **younger sheep as lambs**.

This is basically what we're seeing in Hebrew too, though the word for lamb -- *seh* -- can mean "a young animal" which you then specify, see [Deuteronomy 14:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0514.htm) which says "a sheep *seh* or a goat *seh*."

Not really a big deal here, as young and adult sheep are suitable for sacrifices; Isaac for whatever reason figured if they were carrying all this stuff up the mountain, they were probably sacrificing a young animal (which would, for instance, be the Jews' daily sacrifice as well centuries later); Abraham responds in kind (though at that point he thinks it will probably be his son); and at the end of the story G-d sends them an adult one which has horns for getting tangled.

Comment: +1 for a cogent explanation. However, if I assume [omnisignificance](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/40914878?uid=3739744&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21102152731703), I would want there to be some deeper explanation of the discrepancy between Isaac's expectation and God's provision, as reported by the Torah.

Comment: Well this way it's got to be that much more gut-wrenching for Abraham to say "G-d will provide the young animal" and mean his son. Ask me why G-d then sent a more mature ram? Well, things don't always turn out the way we plan them.

Comment: Yes that is a great answer but another possible answer would be that Isaac being a younger man was more like a lamb.

Comment: I have heard that Isaac had a female soul, and when he was switched with the Ram, who had within it a male soul, he received that masculinity. Perhaps for this reason an adult, sexually mature, masculine Ram was found, it being the appropriate conduit for that soul?

Answer (score 1):

[Rabeynu Bechaya](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38018&st=&pgnum=100&hilite=) ask why the term "איל" (ram) was used here, in contrast to "כבש" (lamb) - the term usually used by the Torah when referring to the sheep used for Korbanos. He explains that this is because a young sheep is called a כבש, and when it grows up it becomes an איל [see Mishna Parah 1:3]. As this ram was one of the ten things listed in Pirkey Avos (5:6) that were created right before Shabbos and was thus 1000+ years old - it was called an איל.

Based on this, we can explain why Avrohom and Yitzchok spoke about a "שה" (another word for a young sheep), as they were surely not expecting to use a 1000+ year old ram as the sacrifice.

Comment: But they didn't speak about a _keves_. They spoke about a _se_. . .

Comment: He says on the previous page that during their conversation both parties knew that the _se_ was actually _Yitzchak_ as well.

Comment: @WAF, I've tried to clarify what I meant..

Comment: +1, Abraham was born 1948, so isaac was 2048 and was 37 for the binding = 2085, so the Ram was actually 2000+ years! o.o